# Fail to pass Value from Lightning Component to Flow

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, salesforcedx, visual-flows

I am passing the values from lightning component to flow using Design Attribute.

On Loading Flow 1 Screen,  I am not getting the values of that attribute passed from lightning component to flow , But when I click on next i.e screen I can see the same value.

Again if I click previous then the values are getting blank.

Is there anything i am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Add a variable in flow of the same data type as that of the design attribute. Include the flow variable in both input and output values.

[image]

Add the flow variable (Record_Id) in the first input text at the top in the right column. This is used for pre-populating any values from the lightning component to the flow when the screen is first viewed. Also, populating this field retains the value of the attribute if the user goes to the next screen and comes back.

Populate the input text Record Id in the 'Store Output Values to Select Variables' section, if you want to use this attribute value later in the flow after this screen.